# Try catch block variable out of scope

Tags: java, scope, null, return, try-catch

I have this bizarre behavior with try catch block. When I initialize variables inside it they are seem to be out of scope for the following code even though i declare them outside..

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;



public class CopyFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        FileOutputStream fos;
        args[0] = "somefile.txt";
        args[1] = "copyithere.txt";
        int i;

        try {
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Input file not found");
                e.getMessage();
            }
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Output file not found");
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Give input and output file name");
            e.getStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            do {
                i = fis.read();
                fos.write(i);
            } while (i != -1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Some IO exception");
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }
}
```

the strange thing is when I declare variables to null "FileInputStream fis = null; then it all turns alright.. isn't declaration without initialization equivalent to initialization to null..?
The other way which gets rid off "out of scope error" is when I put "return;" at the end of catch blocks.. shouldn't the code just run fine with out it? I can see how that could case errors down the line but how does this connects with the "out of scope error for fis and fio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> isn't declaration without initialization equivalent to initialization
>   to null?

**Local variables need to be initialized by the programmer** only, where as instance variables of the class will be initialized by JVM with their default values (based on the type) during object creation.

> The other way which gets rid off "out of scope error" is when I put
>   "return;" at the end of catch blocks.. shouldn't the code just run
>   fine with out it?

There are two possibilities here:

(1) **Green path** scenario: If there is no `FileNotFoundException` in the first `try` block, then `fis` variable would have been initialized successfully, so there will not be any error.

(2) **Red path** scenario: `fis` will not be initialized upon the `FileNotFoundException` in the first `try` block, so if you `return` from the first `catch` block itself, then there is no need of `fis` variable in the last `try` block (because those lines will never be executed because you are returning from the middle), so there is no initialization error.

> When i take the declarations out of the method and make them static it
>   also works.. do you know what is the reason for this distinction?

`static` variables will be initialized with default values (like instance variables) by the JVM, so there will not be any variable initialization errors if you mark them as `static` (JVM already did initialize them).

Comment: ok i  see.. thanks.. so in this case when i take the delarations out of the method and make them static it also works.. do you know what is the reason for this distinction?

Comment: Updated the answer, you can have a look

Comment: You always need to initialize your local variables

Answer (score 1):

> isn't declaration without initialization equivalent to initialization
>   to null..?

Not in case of local variable. Only instance variables are initialised when an instance is created.

> The other way which gets rid off "out of scope error" is when I put
>   "return;"

You should use `try with resources` block introduced in Java 7. It will automatically close the streams, e.g.:

```
int i;
try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);){
    do {
        i = fis.read();
        fos.write(i);
    } while (i != -1);
}
```